# Can I have two rows inside a detail row in kendo grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to make a Kendo grid with rowTemplate and detailTemplate. 
Inside the rowTemplate I want to put an extra row (tr). 
It renders fine, but the last main row does not expand. 
See the example in jsfiddle:

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ericklanford/qzfocx7j/4/)

Templates and grid:

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
    <tr class="k-master-row"> 
        <td class="k-hierarchy-cell"><a href="\#" class="k-icon k-plus"></a></td>
        <td> #= FirstName # </td>
        <td> #= LastName # </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr > 
        <td colspan=4 >#= FirstName # </td>
    </tr>
</script>

<script id="detailTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
    <p>detail stuff</p>
</script>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
 columns:[
          {
              field: "FirstName",
              title: "First Name"
          },
          {
              field: "LastName",
              title: "Last Name"
          }
 ],

dataSource: {
          data: [
              {
                  FirstName: "Joe",
                  LastName: "Smith"
              },
              {
                  FirstName: "Jane",
                  LastName: "Smith"
              }]
},

rowTemplate:kendo.template($("#rowTemplate").html()),
detailTemplate: kendo.template($("#detailTemplate").html())});
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Row template is intended to have a single `<tr>`. If you have multiple, it throws off the selector for the k-master-row. So if you have an extra `<tr>`, last detail row not selectable, if you have 3 `<tr>` last 2 rows not selectable, etc.

One workaround would be to use a `<div>` instead of a `<tr>` for the additional stuff:

```
<script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
    <tr class="k-master-row"> 
        <td class="k-hierarchy-cell"><a href="\#" class="k-icon k-plus"></a></td>
        <td> #= FirstName # </td>
        <td> #= LastName # </td> 
    </tr>
    <div> // extra stuff with a div so selector of detailRow still works...
        <span>#= FirstName # </span>
    </div>
</script>
```